# Is there any vim snippet plugin which is compatible with ideavim?

Tags: vim, pycharm, code-snippets, ideavim, snipmate

I use PyCharm using the Vim emulation feature IdeaVim.
I have tried, without success, to integrate snipMate into PyCharm, which works like a Charm :P in the standard Vim.

Does anybody known if there is a Vim snippet pluging which is compatible with PyCharm? Also, can you use snipMate within PyCharm? It does not even seem to be loaded in my case!

Comment: IdeaVim is basically a keymap, it does not provide Vim functionality by itself and that cannot be added. Therefore, you still need to use the editors' environment. If you need more than simple Vim key commands, you will need to use Vim instead. It is not possible to merge a bloated IDE and Vim.

Comment: IdeaVim is much more than a keymap. It is an emulation of the editing experience of Vim - it has support for modes, mapping, motions and so on. But it does not support VimL, so scripts and plugins such as SnipMate can't work.

Answer (score 0):

IdeaVim doesn't provide the functionality of snippets.
In IntelliJ IDEA snippets are called "Live Templates". They can be used and configured as follows: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html